# SQL SP Return List of Product Images

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, image

I want to get a list of product images from SQL to display in an image slideshow.

However, I am not sure the best way to return the data from the MS SQL stored procedure.

The problem is that with the SP below, I get a duplicate record for each image. Ideally, I'd like to get an array or string list or some way to split out the data from a single record. But, I'm open to other solutions. My goal is to get the images on the page in an intuitive manner. This is for an ASP.Net C# application.

This is the simplified select statement from my stored procedure:

```
  SELECT 

  P.[ProductId]
  ,P.[ProductName]
  ,I.[FileName] as ProductImage

  FROM [Product] P
  LEFT JOIN [ProductImages] I
  on P.ProductId = I.ProductId

  Where P.ProductId = @ProductId
```

This returns data that looks like this:

```
ProductId         ProductName       ProductImage
1                 Coffee Mug        Mug_Image1.jpg
1                 Coffee Mug        Mug_2.jpg
1                 Coffee Mug        Mug_Img3.jpg
```

I'd like it to look like this (but I'd also like to hear other ideas):

```
ProductId         ProductName       ProductImage
1                 Coffee Mug        Mug_Image1.jpg, Mug_2.jpg, Mug_Img3.jpg
```

Again, I'm not sure if this is the best way.

I have two tables. One is Product and the other is ProductImages, which has a FK to the ProductId from the Product table.

Ultimately, I need to construct JSON to feed the client slideshow script. Like this:

```
productimages = [
        { "image": "Mug_Image1.jpg", "caption": "", "link": "", "title": "" },
        { "image": "Mug_2.jpg", "caption": "", "link": "", "title": "" },
        { "image": "Mug_Img3.jpg", "caption": "", "link": "", "title": "" }
                                    ];
```

Here is the C#

```
//Create product object to display on page
ProductEntity product = new ProductEntity();
product.Id = idval;
//Load the product from SP based on ID
ProductWF.LoadProduct(product);

//Render product details on page
ProductNameLabel.Text = product.ProductName;

//Construct JSON image list
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
etc...
```

Comment: If you ultimately need one row of JSON per image, what is wrong with the results coming as one row per image from the database?  It seems like an easy one-to-one mapping...

Comment: Well I also use that same SP to display product information and details. I've edited my above question with the C# to provide some context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT
   P.[ProductId],
   P.[ProductName],
   FileNames = STUFF(
               (SELECT ', ' + FileName FROM ProductImages 
                WHERE ProductId = P.ProductId FOR XML PATH('')) , 1 , 1 , '')
      FROM 
        [Product] P
```

to get your comma separated list of file names for each product, if that helps. But the JSON string you want to generate might be constructed much simpler from the query result you already have.

If you take the query from above, you could map it to a class:

```
public class Product
{
   public int ProductId {get; set;}
   public string ProductName {get; set;}
   public string FileNames {get; set;}
}
```

On the server side you'd have to split the FileNames string property and construct a json string.

Comment: @User970008: where do you get the values for caption, link and title?